# Opsworks/Chef 11.10.4 simple template recipe not creating any file

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

My Chef template code block (`foobar/recipes/default.rb`):

```
template "/tmp/test" do
    group "root"
    owner "root"
    mode "0644"
    source "test.erb"
end
```

And the `test.erb` file (in `foobar/templates/default/test.erb`) :

```
foobar
```

I try to test my recipe on an EC2 instance :

```
# opsworks-agent-cli run_command update_custom_cookbooks
# opsworks-agent-cli run_command execute_recipes
```

No error, but I should have a new file `/tmp/test` created, but having none.

Any clue ?

Edit: in the JSON configuration; I have :

```
  "opsworks": {
    "agent_version": "xxxx",
    "activity": "execute_recipes",
    "valid_client_activities": [
      "reboot",
      "stop",
      "deploy",
      "grant_remote_access",
      "revoke_remote_access",
      "update_agent",
      "setup",
      "configure",
      "update_dependencies",
      "install_dependencies",
      "update_custom_cookbooks",
      "execute_recipes",
      "sync_remote_users"
    ],
```

Comment: Using Chef 11 is dangerous. We haven't put out a security update in yeeeeears. Seriously don't use it.

Comment: I have no choice, this depends on another abstraction specific layer. Next version is in the pipe to use ansible and terraform instead. But I have real issues **now** using legacy code